How can I add panning and zooming feature to react-window?
I want to be able to pan around my virtualized table in all directions instead of using the scrollbars.
I was able to create a virtualized table using react-window and I was able to pan and zoom around using react-zoom-pan-pinch library.
However, I am not able to combine the two.
When I pan around, the whole table moves.
